# Use External DNS Record local with additional subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, nat, synology

We have a server in our LAN which is locally available at a fixed ip. We now have a DDNS Service and a port forwarding rule to make the server available from outside. Additional we added subdomain at our like `server.example.com` pointing to `server.dyndns.com`.

Now we are able to access the Server from outside the LAN. We now want to be able to access the `server.exmple.com` domain from within the LAN. I see two options to do it.

1. Create a NAT rule for all traffic pointing to the external WAN IP. Since we
   have more than one this must be created for each WAN Interface wich is a lot of work since i have to do this for each service
2. Setting up a local DNS Server. Which is not too hard, since we have
   a Synology NAS which has a built in one, which is already present in
   the network as secondary DNS Server redirecting to Googles DNS
   Server. We may need additional subdomains as `server2.example.com`. I thought of a solution where i add a zone for each subdomain. So all the other zones get handled externally and only the internal are addressed by the local DNS Server.

Since i prefer solution number 2 i want to setup the server to redirect `server.example.com` to our internal Server but keeping the `example.com` domain as it is.

Is there a way to do this in a simple way? Otherwise i would stay with solution 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create (what the inside clients would think) was an authoritative copy of example.com and then add your record to it. Read up on **split brain DNS**. So external lookups would get the Internet facing address and internal what ever you defined.

It's actually pretty simple but seems to confuse the crap out of some people.

Comment: perhaps you mean **split horizon DNS**?

Comment: Sure, although I think split horizon is something your software has to support where split brain is done on your side (one looks at who is requesting, the other is 2 different zone databases on 2 different DNS servers). Quite possible I'm conflating two services here, never seen a RFC for split brain but I have seen references to this in several reputable publications.

Comment: like this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS ?

Comment: Not to get into a discussion but that link says "selected by, usually, the source address of the DNS request." I don't think a synology device has this ability.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure it does - http://www.synology.com/support/tutorials_show.php?lang=enu&q_id=584 there's 'limit source ip option'

Comment: the synology is very capable in various aspects. We solved the thing by creating Zones for each subdomain and create one A-Record in it to point to our internal server, this way the external domains dont get touched and we have dns resolution internally